# Smoothings over a real interval

Tags: cv.complex-variables, singularity-theory, fibre-bundles, stein-manifolds

I am asking if somebody knows if the following kind of objects are studied somewhere or if there is some kind of obvious obstruction for them to appear.

Let $(X,0) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be a germ of an isolated irreducible complex surface singularity. Assume that $(X,0)$ does not admit a smoothing.

Is it possible that there exists a (representative) of a smooth manifold $Y \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ together with a map $\pi:Y \to (- \epsilon, \epsilon) $ to a real interval such that (1) $Y$ is a smooth $5$ -dimensional manifold, (2) $\pi$ is smooth and a submersion outside $0$, (3) $\pi^{-1}(0) = X$, and (4) $\pi^{-1}(t)$ is a Stein smooth surface for all $t \neq 0$.

This is a priori weaker than a smoothing which asks the map $\pi$ to be flat and the target and orign space to be analytic. In particular the target space has to have real dimension at least $2$.